# How to name a base class name right?

Tags: c#

I have a model like this image:

[image: 1]

Then, I have created some classes based on the model:

```
public abstract class AccountManager
{
    public void LockAccount(string userId)
    {

    }
}

public class AdministratorTool : AccountManager
{
    public void DeleteAccount(string userId)
    {

    }

    public void UnlockAccount(string userId)
    {

    }
}

public class ModeratorTool : AccountManager
{

}

public class MemberTool : AccountManager
{

}
```

My question: What is the name that I should change with `AccountManager`?

I want to do that because `Account manager` means: provides some methods to do with an account.

Because `DeleteAccount` and `LockAccount` do exactly the same (working with an account), so, putting `DeleteAccount` and `LockAccount` outside `AccountManager` will make changes.

If I still want to keep the two methods inside `AdministratorTool`, I need to change the name of `AccountManager`.

So, can you give me a name for that?

And...my sub question is: may you give me some tips to name a class? There are several questions about how to create a base/derived class but naming a class name.

Thank you!

p/s: this question comes from I'm not good at English :((

Comment: postfix `Base` sometimes makes good name for abstract class, (and prefix `I` for interfaces), if you really have no idea what good name for that will be. its not matter of good or bad English, its matter of knowledge in that subject. how stuff are called in books are usually accepted as good naming practice. so you need to read some books or topics related to subject you are working on.

Comment: The most important thing is to follow/maintain the same pattern. Once you start naming base classes `xxxManager`, keep to that format.

Comment: This is off topic, but inheritance is not usually a good tool for authorization models. https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/05/24/dont-do-role-based-authorization-checks-do-activity-based-checks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Privileges usually tend to accumulate as you go higher in the hierarchy - and you can see the same thing in the real world - A CTO is a specific type of a manager, and a manager is a specific type of employee. Being a CTO does not deny you any of the privileges you had when you was only a low-rank employee. For example - no one would tell the CTO that they can't use the companie's bathroom - as this is a privilege shared by all employees.

So unless a member can do things that a moderator can't or a moderator can do things that an administrator can't , I  wouldn't even bother with an abstract base class.
I would simply have the `Member` class, let the `Moderator` class inherit from `Member` and extend it with moderator and above abilities, and let the `Administrator` class inherit from `Moderator` and extend it with administrator abilities:

```
public class Member
{
     public void LockMyAcount() {/* implementation */}
}

public class Moderator : Member
{
     public void LockAccount(string userId) {/* implementation */}
}

public class Administrator : Moderator 
{
     public void DeleteAccount(string userId) {/* implementation */}
     public void UnlockAccount(string userId) {/* implementation */}
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have read your answer multiple times and I get this: `everything what an employee has can be shared to a boss`, not same to `something what a boss has can be shared to an employee`. Or maybe....i'm wrong

Comment: You are correct. The boss have everything the simple worker have, and then some more. In OOP that's inheritance - A derived class have everything it's parent class have, and then some more.